# Run scalaz tasks on custom pool (ExecutorService)

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have a custom executor service:

```
val executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
```

And I have tasks:

```
val tasks = Task(1).flatMap { i =>
    Task(i + 1)
}
```

I know that I can pass `executorService` to each task:

```
val tasks = Task(1)(executorService).flatMap { i =>
     Task(i + 1)(executorService)
}
```

But what if these tasks are returned from some library and are not created by my code.

How can I run `tasks` using `executorService`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [`Task.fork`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.2/scalaz_2.11-7.2.2-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.concurrent.Task$@fork[A]%28a:=%3Escalaz.concurrent.Task[A]%29%28implicitpool:java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService%29:scalaz.concurrent.Task[A]) :

> Returns a `Task` that produces the same result as the given `Future`, but forks its evaluation off into a separate (logical) thread, using the given `ExecutorService`.

```
val alienTask = Task.delay(5)
val myExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
val myTask = Task.fork(alienTask)(myExecutorService)
```

Comment: Are you sure it also works in case of tasks chained with `flatMap`? I read "Task Concurrency" section from http://timperrett.com/2014/07/20/scalaz-task-the-missing-documentation/ and now I'm confused.

Comment: Most of the time a `Task` will be created with `Task.now`, `Task.delay` or `Task.async` instead of `Task.apply`, so there will not be an "attached" `ExecutionService`. But in your `tasks` example, the task will run on the `executionService` and not on the one you would pass to `fork` yes (like mentioned in that section).

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The underlying task still runs in the default ExecutorService.

Comment: @veegee, isn't that what I mentioned in my previous comment ?